# How can I stack more that two numpy arrays of images along third dimension in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, numpy-ndarray

Here is what I have tried in Python3. I know the problem is that I can't stack the arrays of different shapes as initially, the stacked_data will be empty. But I have to stack a large amount of dataset of images in ndarray format. And I can't do that by passing a tuple of huge numbers. Thank you.

```
from numpy import *
from cv2 import *
import glob

folder_path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\training\WorkWithMam\TestingImages/*.jpg'

image_path = []
for path in glob.glob(folder_path):
    image_path.append(path)

stacked_data = empty((19, 3024, 4032))
for path in folder_path:
    image = imread(path, 0)
    stack((stacked_data, image))
```

Comment: you might wana add the python tag as youll get more support from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended shape of `stacked_data` is `(3024, 4032, 19)`, and you can fill frames using the syntax: `stacked_data[:, :, i] = image`.

The shape of 3D array is illustrated [here](https://fgnt.github.io/python_crashkurs_doc/include/numpy.html):
[image]

As you can see, the order is: (height, width, depth).

You can use a counter to index the "depth" index in each iteration:

```
stacked_data = empty((3024, 4032, 19))
i = 0  # Frame counter (index)

for path in folder_path:
    image = imread(path, 0)
    stacked_data[:, :, i] = image
    i += 1
```

The `stacked_data[:, :, i] = image` slicing syntax means: Set everything in the first and second dimension of `stacked_data` (but third dimension index `i`) to the matching `image` values.

In Python there are always shortcuts...
You can use the following syntax (using [zip](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/) function):

```
stacked_data = empty((3024, 4032, 19))

for path, i in zip(folder_path, range(19)):
    stacked_data[:, :, i] = imread(path, 0)
```